# Extracting Anchor tag with text separately

Tags: javascript, html

I am in JavaScript, I want to extract link from my anchor tag and text of the anchor separately. i.e. I have following anchor tag.

```
<a href="http://www.defconpaintball.com/hiring">Learn More</a>
```

I want to get the "href" in separate variable and the text "Learn More" in separate variable.
How I can do this?

Comment: you mind using jquery ?

Comment: No i want to use javascript only :(

Comment: I have extracted the text "Learn More" now i want to extract "Href" please help me ..

Comment: @ubercooluk: jQuery... to fetch an href? Tell me you're not serious.

Comment: its been years since i used core JavaScript after the amazing jquery was invented,apologize my knowledge in core js

Comment: no not jQuery i want to only use javascript

Comment: Why the tag titanium?

Comment: Because i am working in titanium platform

Comment: And I'm working with chrome. Doesn't mean I should add it. To this question is not relevant as it is purely javascript related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it an id

```
<a id="myLink" href="http://www.defconpaintball.com/hiring">Learn More</a>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ms7bc/1/), you can play with.

```
var anchor = document.getElementById("myLink");

alert(anchor.getAttribute("href")); // Extract link

alert(anchor.innerHTML); // Extract Text
```

---

EDIT:

Don't know what is preventing you from parsing the whole content.

Something like this should be enough:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i in anchors) 
    if(anchors[i].innerHTML=="Learn More") 
        alert(anchors[i].getAttribute("href"));
```

Here is another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ms7bc/2/).

Comment: i dont want to traverse the whole document .. this tag is saved in a variable called anchor .. how can i extract href from that variablke

Comment: this anchor is coming from a website and has no id .. so how i can extract it by id ??

Comment: Well then traverse every anchor on the page until you find the anchor text matching, perhaps?

Comment: Brother Understand the situation the anchor tags are coming from a website through web service. I am storing them in a variable named  anchor.

Comment: it just returns me the this :    <a href="http://www.defconpaintball.com/hiring">Learn More</a>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25065/discussion-between-burhan-mughal-and-loxxy)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 anchor.getAttribute("href")
```

OR

```
<a  href="relativeURL" >
var link = element.a.getAttribute('href')
```

EDIT : I have updated code , try with that

Comment: it is giving me an error .. Undefined is not a function (evaluating 'anchor.getAttribute("href")')

Comment: this anchor is coming from a website and has no id .. so how i can extract it by id ??

Comment: can't find variable element